# VBA clear data in sheet except first Row and Column G

Tags: vba, excel

Can anyone show me how to Clear the content of a sheet without clearing the first Row and Column G?

Comment: In the future please try and post your some code with your question. I really shouldn't have answer the question because SO isn't a code writing service but I was bored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voila!

```
Range("A2:F" & Rows.Count).ClearContents
Range("H2", Cells(Rows.Count, Columns.Count)).ClearContents
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use a [SpecialCells()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157(v=office.15).aspx) method flavor to act (i.e. `ClearContents`) on visible cells only, as follows:

```
Sub main()
    HideMyFavorites True '<--| hide your favorite rows/columns
    Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).ClearContents '<--| clear the content of "visible" cells only
    HideMyFavorites False '<--| unhide your favorite rows/columns
End Sub

Sub HideMyFavorites(doHide As Boolean)
    Columns(7).Hidden = doHide '<--| hide/unhide column "G" (whose column index of "7")
    Rows(1).Hidden = doHide '<--| hide/unhide row "1"
End Sub
```